# enumerated values to web services?

Tags: web-services, http

My dilemma is, basically, how to share an enumeration between two applications.

The users upload documents through a front-end application that is on the web. This application calls a web service of the back-end application and passes the document to it. The back-end app saves the document and inserts a row in the Document table.

The document type (7 possible document types: Invoice, Contract etc.) is passed as a parameter to the web service's UploadDocument method. The question is, what should the type (and possible values) of this parameter be?

Since you need to hardcode these values in both applications, I think it is O.K. to use a descriptive string (Invoice, Contract, WorkOrder, SignedWorkOrder).

Is it maybe a better approach to create a DocumentTypes enumeration in the first application, and to reproduce it also in the second application, and then pass the corresponding integer value to the web service between them?

Comment: What language is this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speak about .net, but if you have an ASP.net Webservice, you should be able to add an enumeration directly to it.

When you then use the "Add Web Reference" in your Client Application, the resulting Class should include that enum

But this is from the top of my head, i'm pretty sure i've done it in the past, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET you can create an enumeration on the back end. Then create a web reference on the front end to that back end web service. That will then pick up the enumeration and expose it there on the front end, while only having it defined in one place.

The advantage with using the enumerations is that you can expose those on the front end, avoiding the problem of users passing in bad values. If you were to use an integer, that isn't very friendly and you'd have to check it at some point. Similar problem with strings. So if you have a well known set of values, I'd highly recommend using an enumeration.